# CameraCaptureUI presents window with cropping box how can I control the initialize size of it

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm using the CameraCaptureUI and it presents window to the user with a resizeable cropping box embedded in the window, how can I control the initialize size of the cropping box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer very soon after asking the question here of course, you need to change the aspect ratio on this line of code to affect the size of the cropped 
    window:Size aspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);